# Generate a matrix from an excel worksheet [ExcelBundle-Symfony]

Tags: php, excel, type-conversion

I made the follow function for get a matrix from a worksheet.

```
private function getMatrixFromSheet($worksheet){
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if (!is_null($cell)) {
                $matrix[$cell->getRow()][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

In this way if I want to access to the second row, second col cell, I can do `$matrix[2]['B']`.

I need to be able to access to the matrix indexes both as number in order to access to the previous cell as `$matrix[2][2]`.

Is there a way to do this?
I try to convert `$cell->getColumn()` result in a integer, but unfortunately `(int) "a" == 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a numeric value for the column, then PHPExcel provides a static helper method to do precisely that

```
$columnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($cell->getColumn());
```

Which returns 1 for column `A`, 2 for column `B`, 27 for column `AA`, 28 for column `AB`, etc

However, you might find that you can simplify your function completely, because PHPExcel also provides the `toArray()` method to do exactly what you've written this method for:

```
private function getMatrixFromSheet($worksheet){
    return $worksheet->toArray();
}
```

Note that row/column offsets for the matrix returned by `toArray()` are 0-based

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I need! Unfortunately I didn't see the `toArray` method, this could make me save time!

Comment: Anyway I'm trying to use `PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString ` method but i need to add also the `use` statement for the namespace of PHPExcel_Cell. Which it is?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ExcelBundle for Symfony, but as PHPExcel isn't namespaced, I suspect it's probably treated as being in the global namespace

Comment: Found It! I don't know if it's my config issue or it ExcelBundle work as this, anyway i need to add `use PHPExcel_Cell;`. Going to update you solution